# Blank design tab in android studio

Tags: android-studio

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TwJaw.jpg
The design tab for my Android Studio doesn't display even the starting Hello World or my project name,  does anybody know how to make this display and update as I write my program ?

edit:  I'm not sure how the code will help, the tutorial im following says that the design tab should look like this upon opening https://i.stack.imgur.com/1zUVb.jpg and update as I code.  I think it's a problem with the settings of android studio because the only code i've changed is what they have told me to.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#0d7429"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="25dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:text="@string/Hello_World_Text"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:fontFamily="cursive" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Add code instead of images so we can help.

Comment: With images we can only see the result, not what may have caused the result. Code is much more useful here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because  you have an error in your xml.
Changing `TextView` to `android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView` works if you want to use "app" name space prefix for `app:fontFamily`. However,you can also use `android` namespace prefix  for `fontFamily` but it is only compatible with API version 16 and higher.

Comment: I have changed it and tried both multiple times but my design is still the first picture I linked above  (i updated the code to the new code)

Comment: Is it showing a preview when you switch to the TEXT tab?

Comment: The text tab just shows me all of my code, I only see the result when I run the emulator

Comment: I can drag a button onto the design preview and the button shows up under the constraint layout as an object, but there is no visible button

Comment: preview is on the right top corner of the text tab [image](https://imgur.com/a/0TZbIid)

Comment: There will probably be a tiny,red (!) exclamation mark in the preview .click on it and post what does it say

Comment: My preview is still default and doesn't have the text or background or buttons or anything https://imgur.com/a/pOobaEs

Comment: yes there is that exclamation mark, click on it and it will tell you the problem.Then you can update your question with the error

Answer (score 0):

go to app/res/values/styles.xml
if it says:

`<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">`

change it to

`<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">`

Comment: Why should that be changed? What is the reason the former value doesn't work?